# TortoiseHG with bitbucket for handling lots of projects

Tags: bitbucket, tortoisehg

Hi i have created more than 100 projects each projects are replicated, so my problem is for any small change i have to change 100 java files,

can i handle this with TortoiseHG

for example

[image]

it should look like this

so whenever I change on A file it should reflect on all the projects

but here keep also in mind that package name is different in all Java (according to project) so it should not change only the code I change will reflect

Comment: Are you using Mercurial or SVN?

Comment: Hi @alroc actually i am using Mercurial with TortoiseHg

Comment: Then I'm going to edit your post to remove all references to Subversion. "svn tortoisehg" (from your original title) is confusing and misleading as they're two independent pieces of software.

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of scenario where you want to turn your A file into a library and then reuse it.  With Subversion you'd do that with [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html).